# ember-data findAll returns 0 records on first request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Where is the best place to boot strap ember-data in order to fill the store:

I am currently using revision 13 of ember-data.

At the moment I am trying this in the ApplicaitonRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: ->
    App.Contact.find().then (contacts) ->
      console.log contacts.get('length')
```

What I am finding is that the console.log statement above will log 0 but if I then type:

```
App.Contact.find().get('length')
```

into the console, the length is as I would expect, i.e. greater than 0.

I am confused as to what is going on, I would have thought that the promise would not be resolved until the records are materialized.

I've gone through the code and the json is parsed out in the serializer and I cannot work out why the length is 0 the first time.

I can't create a fiddle for this as it only happens when connecting to our backend store through the rest adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer after creating an issue on github:

Actually, DS.Model.find() return a 'promistified' RecordArray whch promise is resolved when the recordarray is loaded (ie its isLoaded propery is true). The problem is that DS.Model.find() is loaded as soon as the array is created, as a consequence the promise is resolved.

In order to fix your problem (because I think you want to return a live array), something like this should work:

```
App.Contact.find({}).then(contacts) ->
   return App.Contact.all()
```

This way, under the hood, you are calling a findQuery, which is loaded when the backend returns the records, not at the array creation

Comment: i have a question - its really odd. why does it only work when i pass in an empty object on the find. if you just do App.Contact.find() - its going to call on the promise function before it actually finish its ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the best place to boot strap ember-data in order to fill the store:

The best place is in the model hook (instead of setupController) because ember router will wait for each model hook's promise to resolve before moving on to the next. So for example:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Contact.find()
```

> I am confused as to what is going on, I would have thought that the promise would not be resolved until the records are materialized.

Agreed that is surprising. I'll see if I can find a way to reproduce. One thing you might try is enabling the XMLHttpRequests in chrome developer tools so you can see if the promise is really resolving before ajax comes back. Thinking it could also be a bindings issue, like maybe the promise resolves at right time but the length property wont update till next run loop.